# Reading large binary files

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, c++builder, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am working on a project where I am logging some signals (1D arrays) into a binary file. I can store large amount of data (usually several giga bytes). Now I would like to load those files back.

I have two visual components. One is called Overview and other is just a plain Y/T chart. Overview should give users idea what is in the complete file (large file) while chart just shows a part of the file usually part which is selected in overview with resizable rectangle/band.

Because files can be really large loading to memory is not optimal at all so the main idea is to load to memory (max. several MB) only important data / visible data. So loading and displaying is done on user demand. If user zooms on chart, data needs to be reloaded with more data points from file.

My question is how to draw Overview component to show the whole content of file in the best way (without really loading all samples from file). Let's say my files are larger than 10GB and I would like to give users idea what is in file but I can draw max. 16k samples on Overview component?

Is there any method to store any additional data (like indexing, smaller data chunks, images...) during logging for later loading and drawing Overview component? Currently I am storing only samples but adding additional data wouldn't be a problem. Do you have any experiences with that an how you did it?

To get an idea what I am doing:

[image]

Comment: I don't really get the question. It's easy enough to read only part of a file.

Comment: Well there is large amount of samples in file. For overview I need to show complete file but it's pointless to load complete file while i cannot show all data on screen but I still have to give users the overview what is in file. For chart part I am displaying/loading only part of file which user selects in overview window with red rectangle. However "worst" case would be to select complete overview window which means that I have to re-load complete file but again I cannot do that.. just every N-th sample. I hope I explained it.

Comment: Not really. Sounds vague.

Comment: Let's say I have a large file with more than 10G samples. To draw overview I have to virtually display all those 10GB samples but there are two things to think about. First is that I cannot just load all samples to memory and second is that drawing 10GB points on screen is not efficient at all. Basically I have to draw a waveform of file but I don't need all data because it's just an overview. So I have to virtually stuff all those 10GB into overview buffer of 16kSamples. So how to draw such waveform?

Comment: Well, how do you want to represent the data?

Comment: "some signals (1D arrays)" That is not much information to go on. The answer depends very much on the structure of your file. Please describe it in more detail (example), or if it is not yet set in stone, describe the requirements the file structure should have.

Comment: After some research about this topic I am actually searcing for best or let's say efficient caching of data for fast drawing. Similar to audio programs which shows complete waveform but when you zoom in you can see sampling points.

Comment: In the overview, I would really load every nth sample (perhaps with a slight oversampling and linear interpolation to make it look a little smoother). If you want to zoom, simply load only the samples in the zoom "window". I assume that is what other programs would do too. If you screen is, say 2560 pixels wide, you only need to read (with 2x oversampling) 5120 samples. Which samples these are depends on your zoom window. Caching can be done manually, but I assume that if you use memory mapped files, the caching is done by the OS anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use multi-level decimation - just store every Nth, N^2th and so on samples (for example, 10th, 100, 1000, 10000...). When user changes window size, choose appropriate level, which contains about 1000 samples in this window, load and show these samples quickly (1000 points is just reasonable number for a chart on screen).

If your data have some features, peculiar properties, it is possible to get bigger (level-up) data set and apply [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) polyline simplification algorithm to preserve the features.

Comment: Why pick 10 as the base?

Comment: That makes sense. I've got the idea now. Maybe the only problem I see with decimation is that signals should apply to Nyquist theorem and probabyl I should do some filtering to avoid anti-aliasing. This is basically a resampling. I will look up in this way, it sounds promising and it makes sense. I've heard of Douglas-Peucker algorithm but I never think about it. It's quite a challenge to work on large data and extract useful info. Thanks for your ideas

Comment: @David 10 is just example.

Comment: I checked out Audacity source where they are doing some kind of a caching of wave files. They draw all points only when necessary (when zoomed in). I still have to dig a bit deeper to get more information about that but I get the basic idea.

Comment: depending on the data you may want to get the average or mean of a number of samples for displaying the zoomed out portion.

Answer (score 1):

When I write to file I write several data chunks with fixed size (depends on DAQ samplerate). After fixed count of those chunks was written I add one statistic chunk which holds information about how many data chunks has been written and Maximum, Minimum, Average and Variance calculated from all written data chunks together. Then I repeat it... until recording is stopped by user.

```
File struct is:

[File header]
[DataChunk1]
[DataChunk2]
...
[DataChunkN]
[StatsChunk1]
[DataChunkN+1]
[DataChunkN+2]
...
[DataChunkN+..]
[StatsChunk2]
....
```

When I want to load file and draw data I just recalc what data/px ratio I have currently set with zoom on my chart. There are two situations. If zoom is really in thus the data/px ratio is <=1 I need to load appropriate amount of data from file (from data chunks) and display it on chart (do some interpolation if neccesary). Drawing is simple... just line from point to point because we are showing all data.

In case when ratio is >1 I load appropriate count of statistic chunks (instead of data chunks) and use them to draw a chart. First I draw an envelope with Minimum and Maximum (two series with painted area between them), then I draw one series which is Average +/- std. deviation (sqrt(Variance). That way I can show an overview of data in this chunks. Because I am reading only statistic chunks reading performance is really good (fast). If file is large enough that statistic chunks count / px ratio gets greater than 1 I can simply decimate statistic chunks and do the drawing.

About count of chunks to load etc... I have to experiment a bit to see what gives me the best results but first trials were really encouraging. Later I will add some comments about end results and a photo to show it. Thanks for your ideas and contributions.